# How to load ssl_certificate based on requested $host [nginx virtual host]?

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, virtualhost

I have a long virtual server for my nginx server. It's going to be shared between multiple domains and changes on this file should be affected on all domains. Everything goes fine until I reached to the ssl configuration. I have to load proper certificate for each host. unfortunately it's impossible to achieve this by using $host in file path:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/$host/fullchain.pem
```

neither it's not possible to put this directive inside if block like this:

```
if ($host = "example.com") {
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/example.com/fullchain.pem;
}
```

so is it possible to do this without splitting up `server` blocks?

Comment: You can, but you need to use `$ssl_server_name`, as `$host` is unknown at the time the certificate is required. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate).

Comment: would you like to write this in an answer? if yes, inform about the performance issue please. It'll be the best answer. @RichardSmith